# Is there any way to call Xamarin.Essentials.WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync with Ephemeral Browser (clean new session)?

Tags: xamarin.forms, oauth, xamarin.essentials

I am trying to use Xamarin.Essentials for authentication with Google or Microsoft.
However, the issue is that *they use a "regular" browser mode*.
So, for example, if I have something cached in my cookies on the mobile device, and I have signed in into the Auth service previously, **it would just not ask me the user's credentials** and proceed with the Authentication automatically, even if **I need to sign in with another user's credentials**.

And example of what I am looking for is similar to iOS:

```
    authSession.PrefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession = true;
```

But Xamarin.Essentials don't seem like have any such option.
So, is there any way to implement it in PCL project?

*JIC, the approach with simple cleaning of cookies like `cookieManager.RemoveAllCookie();` doesn't help.*